# vertical align cell contents in tabu environment

Tags: tabu

I am wondering how to vertically align (ie, top/middle/bottom) a cell's contents in a `tabu` environment.

Its manual says something about "column types" (p. 9 and 10) and specifies `p`, `m` and `b` as possible values.

How do they exactly work?

Comment: make small example and test different column type ... i.e. learn-by-doing. Of course, options `b`, `m`, have sense in multi-line cells. Types `` and `m` are the same as other tables. Maybe will help to search through SE for `tabu` ...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you show a specific problem where this should be useful?